How to avoid the focus gain of my virtual-keyboard over the text fields
I have made a virtual keyboard with tkinter in python. When i click one of the letters my tkinter window gains the 'focus' and therefore my focus will not be anymore in the text field so the program cant type the letter where i want.
My idea is to do a virtual keyboard like the provided by windows tools, when you click a letter in that window u dont take the focus from the text field. thats the feature i want to know. anyway thank u for ur time and thanks if u have an answer
I cant find a library or a clear example of which function would work for me in this case, or may be i dont know how to look for them on google

you can use the takefocus option along with setting the window attributes.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

Tkinter doesn't have support for that. You will need to make it platform dependent and call functions from the WinAPI or X11. Alternatively you try using another library gui like qt
